# How to convert 00:03:30 in 3m30s

Tags: php, date, time, format

I search for my problem on php.net and on stackoverflow and I did'nt find a good answer to solve my problem, so I decide to ask it !

I have a number of secs :

```
210
```

I transform it to **00:03:30** :

```
gmdate('H:i:s', 210);
```

But how can I format my answer like :
3m30s or 3min30secs ?

I think I can make this transformation by Exploding my results and concatenate with variable, but I don't know if it's the best solution...

```
$part = explode(":", $mytime);
$hours = $part[0];
$mins = $part[1];
$secs = $part[2];

$hoursvar = "h";
$minsvar = "m";
$secsvar = "s";

$timefinal = $hours.$hoursvar.$mins.$minsvar.$secs.$secsvar;
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo ltrim(date("H", 210), "0")." hours, ".
     ltrim(date('i', 210), "0")." min, ".
     ltrim(date('s', 210), "0")." secs";
```

Comment: +1 for ltrim. much better than my former strpos/substr attempt. :)

Answer (score 1):

`date()` works a little bit like `printf()`. You pass a format string containing a defined set of meta characters which will be replaced by values. Note that the format string can contain any content not just meta characters. The [manual page explains this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) as well. You can use:

```
date('i\ms', 210);
```

You see that you have to escape literals (the `m`) to that they were not replaced by values.

I hope you can live with a leading zero : `03m30`

if not, use:

```
$date = date('i\ms', 210);
if(strpos($date, '0') === 0) {
    $date = substr($date, -strlen($date) + 1);
}
```

Or, shorter, thanks @Orangepill :) :

```
$date = ltrim(date('i\ms', 210), '0');
```

as there is no meta character for minutes without leading zeros known by `date()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can format the string inside gmdate, just escape the characters you want to print:

```
$sec = 210;
echo gmdate("i\m s\s", $sec);
```

Output:

```
03m 30s
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easy, your current date format is **H:i:s** and you want to convert it to **i:s**

So you do the following

```
$date = "00:03:30";
$new_date = date("i_s-",strtotime($date));
```

Since we can't insert the letters m and s in the function we can use **str_replace** to replace the **_** with **m** and replace **-** with **s** so

```
$new_date = str_replace("_","m",$new_date);
$new_date = str_replace("-","s",$new_date);
```

That was the best way I could think of.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string_time = '00:03:30';
$int_time = strtotime(date('Y-m-d').' '.$string_time);
echo date('i', $int_time).'m'.date('s', $int_time).'s';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$seconds = 210;
$date = gmdate("H\h:i\m:s\s", $seconds);
echo preg_replace('/0([0-9])/','$1', $date);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
0h:3m:30s
```

You can use gmdate with preg_replace to remove 0 from begining.

OR more advanced

```
$seconds = 210;
$date = gmdate("H\h:i\m:s\s", $seconds);
$match = array('/0([0-9])/','/s/','/m\:/','/h\:/');
$replace = array('$1', ' sec ', ' min ', ' hours ');
echo preg_replace($match,$replace, $date);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
0 hours 3 min 30 sec
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo ltrim(date("H", 210), "0")." hours, ".
     ltrim(date('i', 210), "0")." min, ".
     ltrim(date('s', 210), "0")." secs";
```

**Thanks to Orangepill !**